# Is the preprocessor macro "#define TRUE FALSE'" valid?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Is the following define statement valid in C?

```
#define TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: This would lead to confusion only if `TRUE` and `FALSE` are used, which means are `#define`ed somewhere else. The latter would then lead to compiler warnings.

Comment: You should just try it, before asking "Will it work?"

Comment: @Paco Upated my question, Is it not a good question yet?

Comment: A similar java horror you might find interesting;  http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Disgruntled-Bomb-Java-Edition.aspx

Comment: I can sort of understand not wanting to try this before asking. Im sure its effects won't permeate beyond the end of the program but it does have an earth shattering look to it

Comment: Looks a bit like `define struct union` ultimate memory saver ;)

Comment: This question should not be downvoted.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You have to remember that preprocessor macros are simply substituted. If you do e.g.

```
#define TRUE FALSE
```

then the processor simply replaces all places where it finds `TRUE` will be replaced by whatever `FALSE` is defined to.

So indeed it's a good definition. And yes it will most likely change the program workflow, possibly in very unexpected ways that may even cause undefined behavior.

Answer (score 4):

Since we should expect  `TRUE` is already defined when `FALSE` is defined too.
So in this case this would be a redefinition and be invalid.
If you stay intern the `#define TRUE FALSE` would be valid to the standard, but would be invalid according to all logics I could imagine.

But a way i have already often seen was :

```
#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE !FALSE
```